# Why can chain rule not be applied recursively (reapplied to outer function)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, chain-rule

1. $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$
2. $f(x)=(x+1)^{\frac 12}$
3. $\frac {d}{dx}f(x)=\frac {d}{dx}[(x+1)^{\frac 12}]·\frac {d}{dx}(x+1)$
4. $\frac {d}{dx}f(x)\neq[\frac {d}{dx}[(x+1)^{\frac 12}]·\frac {d}{dx} (x+1)]·\frac {d}{dx}(x+1)$

Why can chain rule not be reapplied to $\frac {d}{dx}[(x+1)^{\frac 12}]$ in step three even though it is also a composite function (it looks the same as $f(x)$). Is it just a rule that chain rule can only be applied once? Does Leibniz's notation explain it?

Comment: Why do you thin it can't be applied; derivative of $x+1$ is 1 so you would just be multiplying by 1

Comment: You misunderstand the chain rule. You want to take the derivative of the outer function with respect to the inner function, not the outer function with respect to the independent variable.

Comment: (Ab)using Leibniz’s notation, $\frac d{dx}f(x)=\frac d{d(x+1)}[(x+1)^{\frac12}]\cdot\frac d{dx}(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain rule is the following:

$$ [f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))g'(x) $$

So, when we want differentiate things like $\sqrt{1+x}$, we do $f(x) = x^{1/2}$ and $g(x)= 1+x$ . Then, we get

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \implies f'(g(x)) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}$$

$$g'(x) = 1 $$

Replacing in the formula for the chain rule:

$$ [f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))g'(x)  $$
$$ (\sqrt{1+x})' =  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}} $$

Maybe you are confused with the notation.

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule can be applied recursively.

For example,
if
$a(x)
=f(g(h(x)))
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
a'(x)
&=(f(g(h(x))))'\\
&=(g(h(x))'f'(g(h(x)))
\qquad\text{chain rule applied to } f\\
&=h'(x)g'(h(x))f'(g(h(x)))
\qquad\text{chain rule applied to } g\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score -1):

The chain rule can be expressed as $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$. It logically follows that  $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dv} \frac{dv}{dx}$.